# Trying to display instantly the result of a user editing action when clicking an image in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, qt5, qgraphicsscene

I am trying to implement an image editor with some customized image edition tools not present in the Qt image classes. When the user clicks on the image scene to perform some operation, I want the image to be instantly updated in the GUI application, showing in real time to the user the changes (drawing pixels, zooming...). The problem is that the actions to edit the image when clicking can only be done (at least to my knowledge) inside a separate class (in the example I show below, such class is called GraphicsScene), and thus I don't know how to transfer the edited image to the MainWindow class.

In short, I would like to "send" the edited image from the GraphicsScene class to the MainWindow class immediately after the user performs an action to edit the image, and then make the latter one execute the code to update the screen in real time after each user action is performed on the image.

For the sake of clarity, I next show the scheme of the code I have for now.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:

private:

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include "graphicsscene.h"

extern QImage Image_original, Image_modified;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_Image_triggered()
{
    QDir dir;

    QString filename=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                  tr("Open Background"),
                                                  path,
                                                  tr("Images (*.png *.bmp *.jpg *.jpeg);;All files (*.*)"));

    Image_original.load(filename);
    GraphicsScene * img = new GraphicsScene( this );
    img->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Image_original));
    ui->preview->setScene(img);
}
```

In order to be able to track the coordinates when clicking, and following some suggestions around the net, I created a subclass of QGraphicsScene called GraphicsScene, whose header file is:

**graphicsscene.h**

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSSCENE_H
#define GRAPHICSSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QPointF>
#include <QList>

class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GraphicsScene(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent);
signals:

public slots:

private:
    int x, y;
};

#endif // GRAPHICSSCENE_H
```

Finally, to perform the image editions, the source file associated is:

**graphicsscene.cpp**

```
#include "graphicsscene.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern QImage Image_original, Image_modified;

GraphicsScene::GraphicsScene(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    this->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::gray);
}

void GraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
    if (mouseEvent->button()==Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        x=mouseEvent->scenePos().x();
        y=mouseEvent->scenePos().y();
    }
    Image_modified=some_custom_image_editing_code(Image_original, x, y);
}
```

Ideally, I would like to execute the following action in MainWindow after the mousePressEvent is performed:

```
img->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Image_modified));
ui->preview->setScene(img);
```

I would **highly** appreciate any idea.

Comment: Please explain yourself better, it is not necessary that you spend many lines in telling your internet search since they deviate what you want to explain.

Comment: I do not understand this part: "I want to implement an action consisting of duplicating the zoom in a way that the image is centered according to the clicked coordinates, but keeping its resolution by cropping the image accordingly". The zoom scales the QGraphicsview and will therefore change the way the QGraphicsPixmapItem is changed, but not the QPixmap. Or maybe you want to center the image?

Comment: Let's assume the screen size is 400x200 (for instance). You load a 400x200 image as well. If you click at, let's say, the pixel (200, 50), then the new image would consist on getting the pixels from 101 to 300 horizontally and from 1 to 100 vertically, and then it would be zoomed such that the new size is again 400x200. But, getting to the point, as per request, what I want is, whatever the change is done to the image, a method to "send" this information from the class GraphicsScene to the class MainWindow in order to paint the image at the scene "img" with the new changes once they are done.

Comment: You want the zoom action to return an image of the same size as the original but with the cropped data

Comment: In conclusion if you have an image of `w*h`, then click on the point `P(x1, y1)`, scaling the cut image of `w/2*h/2` centered on P, and it must be scaled aw * h and send it to the Mainwindow . If you just want to get the QPixmap you do not need to zoom, instead if you want the cut to be shown if it is necessary to zoom, which of these 2 options do you want?

Comment: Exactly, but, as stated before, this is not my main issue, probably because you were right pointing out that my initial question was so vague. Let's forget for now about the zooming, and let's assume that what we want is to perform complex image editing actions that cannot be done solely with the Qt functions, and that these actions involve mouse tracking. This forces the situation expounded above, working with a new class. And what I would like to know is how to trigger the action from the MainWindow to update the image immediately after the user makes some change to the image with the mouse.

Comment: Ok, I understand, in a moment I show my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to click the item containing the pixmap it is not necessary to overwrite the QGraphicsScene mousePressEvent method, since you could click outside the image, it is better to overwrite that method in QGraphicsPixmapItem.

Instead of using extern to access the images, in Qt is better signals and slot, but only the classes that inherit from QObject can have these attributes, unfortunately QGraphicsPixmapItem does not inherit from this, but we can use it as interface.

**graphicspixmapitem.h**

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSPIXMAPITEM_H
#define GRAPHICSPIXMAPITEM_H

#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QObject>

class GraphicsPixmapItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GraphicsPixmapItem(QObject *parent=0);

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);

signals:
    void newPixmap(const QPixmap p);
};

#endif // GRAPHICSPIXMAPITEM_H
```

**graphicspixmapitem.cpp**

```
#include "graphicspixmapitem.h"

#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

GraphicsPixmapItem::GraphicsPixmapItem(QObject * parent):QObject(parent)
{

}

void GraphicsPixmapItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPoint p = QPoint(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y());
    QPixmap pix = pixmap();
    if(!pix.isNull()){
        QRect rect(QPoint(), pix.rect().size()/2);
        rect.moveCenter(p);
        QPixmap modified = pix.copy(rect);
        modified = modified.scaled(pix.rect().size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
        emit newPixmap(modified);
    }
    QGraphicsPixmapItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

In the previous code we created the signal newPixmap, this connected it with a slot called onNewPixmap in MainWindow.

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "graphicsscene.h"
#include "graphicspixmapitem.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_actionOpen_triggered();
    void onNewPixmap(const QPixmap pixmap);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    GraphicsPixmapItem *item;
    GraphicsScene *scene;

    QPixmap original_pixmap;
    QPixmap new_pixmap;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new GraphicsScene(this);
    ui->preview->setScene(scene);
    item = new GraphicsPixmapItem;
    /*ui->preview->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    ui->preview->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);*/
    scene->addItem(item);
    connect(item, &GraphicsPixmapItem::newPixmap, this, &MainWindow::onNewPixmap);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{

    QString path = QDir::homePath();
    QString filename=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                  tr("Open Background"),
                                                  path,

                                                  tr("Images (*.png *.bmp *.jpg *.jpeg);;All files (*.*)"));

    original_pixmap = QPixmap(filename);
    item->setPixmap(original_pixmap);
}

void MainWindow::onNewPixmap(const QPixmap pixmap)
{

    new_pixmap = pixmap;
    QFile file("new_file.png");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    new_pixmap.save(&file, "PNG");
}
```

In that slot as test I save the image in the folder where the executable is generated.

In your code I see that you use QImage, if you want to continue using it you can convert QPixmap to QImage with:

```
new_pixmap.toImage()
```

The complete example is found [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/QGraphicsPixmapItemExample)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for the great explanation!

Just one small clarification for future readers. In order to get it to work as required (update screen after each click), it suffices to replace the inner code from void MainWindow::onNewPixmap(const QPixmap pixmap) by the following line:

    item->setPixmap(pixmap);

Comment: You did not say that you wanted it to show, at least in your initial question. Edit your question and add that remark, please.

Comment: I was editing the question after your first message pointing out that needed to be explained better. Please, tell me if now you find it more properly written.

Comment: That part is not important, I think it is easily deduced.

Comment: Do not focus too much on reporting your failed searches, focus on your problem, as you deviate and often bored reading those things.